# Query in historic table with thousands of rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to do a query with thousands of tuples. I need to save the first ID, last ID and date saved in a historic table by day in a new table. I have data from 2020 to 2022. Every day could 600.000 rows or more. I have thought two solutions:

1. Doing a query every time with limit 600.000 and save the first id, last id and date, all of this order by dates or ids.
2. Doing a query day by day and get the first and the last id.

The problems are that these querys could delay so much because i am doing orderings.

I´m doing this with SQL and need execute this in PHP with a cron every day to save the data of the day. First, i´m building the new table with the data of past.

Someone would know one tip or antoher form to do this.

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this ([result here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/X6ZocrJ38ZMjLZcwRyKSq/0))

```
select date, min(id) as min, max(id) as max 
from logs
group by date
```

Comment: Not possible, Query could delayed more than one hour...

Comment: can't you use trigger ?